# UDP no longer allowed to send on android 7+?

Tags: wi-fi, udp

So I have been running an app on android (Samsung Note 4) with out trouble until the latest phones started coming out with android 7+ (Samsung S8, OnePlus3T).    Now I find that UDP is blocked on the phone in the app.

Is there a **new setting that blocks UDP broadcasts**?

I used Evothings app to test that UDP is blocked.

I noticed a change with the way WiFi works on android. If the WiFi connection doesn't have internet, the system seems to behave differently.  Does WiFi work differently if there is no internet?

Again, it still works with the older versions of android.  If you have come across this problem please share.

Comment: Please don't cross-post [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509371/latest-android-no-longer-sends-udp-broadcast-packets) on multiple SE sites. It's very rare that the same question is on-topic on several sites, and as you've found, it splits up answers, making it harder for future visitors to find information.

Comment: @DanHulme I am asking about settings here.  I am not asking how to program.  This is specific to the user group because it is settings.  Turns out that I couldn't find a setting, though the question is very relevant.  I would still like to know if there is some setting that changes the WiFi or UDP connections in the newer android versions.

Comment: @DanHulme I have modified the question.  I am looking for info on settings.  Please re-open the question.  I would like to understand if people feel WiFi has changed.  And if there is a setting for UDP.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the newer versions require another call to set that you want to multi broadcast over UDP.

I could not find any setting that relates to UDP or how WiFi works without internet connection.